# Why is my media tag not working with my styled ocmponent?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I am trying to add a `@media` to a `styled-component`.  Here is my Component:

```
const Image = styled.img`
  display: none;
  @media(width >= 600px) {
    display: block;
  };
`;
```

The `@media` is never triggered.  What am I doing wrong?  How do we get `@media` tags to work with `styled-components`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your media query is wrong, as you would do for standard CSS you need to specify the `min-width` like:

```
@media (min-width: 600px) { 
   display: block;
}
```